# Get a field from associated in grouping mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB which as associated field to another collection like below:

**ProcessError**

```
{
  id: "error-1",
  error: "Error 1",
  process: {"$ref": "col2", "$id": "Something"}
}
```

**Process**

```
{
  id: "process-1",
  title: "Hello"
}
```

I want to group by ProcessError.process.id and get ProcessError.process.title, I did it like that

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("process.id").in(processIds)),
    group("process.id").count().as("total"),
    project("total").and("title").previousOperation()
);

AggregationResults<Map> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
   agg,
   ProcessError.class,
   Map.class
);
```

but it returns whole ProcessError.process not just ProcessError.process.title as title

Comment: Try including the `$` sign in the field name as in `match(Criteria.where("process.$id").in(processIds)),
    group("process.$id").count().as("total"),`

Comment: it's already return the process but whole entity ( spring data handle association ) I need just title, how it can help me? any idea? @chridam